# TypeScript Conditional Generic Type with Object Properties and Values

Tags: typescript, generics, conditional-statements, typescript-generics

I want to create a conditional generic type/interface for an object in TypeScript.
Let´s say I have the following interface:

```
    interface CarType{
        name: string;
        price: number;
    }

    // Which will allow this Object

    const ferrari: CarType = {
        name: "Ferrari F50",
        price: 300000,
    }
```

I want to create an interface or type that allows the following.

Note: These are examples. To make it clear what the PartOfObjectType should achieve

```
// Should compile
const partOfFerrari: PartOfObjectType<CarType> = {
    prop: "price",
    value: 300000 // All numbers should work because the property price has the type number
 }
 
 // Should not compile
 const partOfFerrari: PartOfObjectType<CarType> ={
    prop: "price",
    value: false // Should not work because property price has the type number
 }
 
 // Should compile
 const partOfFerrari: PartOfObjectType<CarType> ={
    prop: "name",
    value: "Banana" // All strings should work because the property name has the type string
 }
 
 // Should not compile
 const partOfFerrari: PartOfObjectType<CarType> ={
    prop: "name",
    value: 342123 // Should not work because property name has the type string
 }
 
 // Should not compile
 const partOfFerrari: PartOfObjectType<CarType> ={
    prop: "color", // Color does not exist in CarType
    value: 342123 
 }
 
 // Should not compile
 const partOfFerrari: PartOfObjectType<CarType> ={
    prop: "name", 
    // value is missing
 }
 
 // Should not compile
 const partOfFerrari: PartOfObjectType<CarType> ={
    value: "Ferrari F50", 
    // prop is missing
 }
```

I have tried the following. Type suggestions for the prop are working. But I just cannot get the type suggestions for value to work.

```
interface PartOfObjectType<ObjectType> {
    prop: keyof ObjectType;
    value: ObjectType[prop];
}

// I´ve also tried


interface PartOfObjectType<ObjectType> {
    prop: keyof ObjectType;
    value: ObjectType[keyof ObjectType];
}
```

I´ve read all about generics and conditionals but just can´t find anything that makes it work with objects.

I´m thankful for any help

Comment: Yes I´ll edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `PartOfObjectType` as follows:

```
type PartOfObjectType<T extends object> =
  { [K in keyof T]-?: { prop: K, value: T[K] } }[keyof T];
```

This *distributive object type* (using the term coined in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109)) is created by [mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over the properties of `T` to form a new object type with the same keys and whose values are the desired `{prop, value}` pairs, and then immediately [indexing into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) it with the keys of `T` to produce a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of its property value types.

(In case it matters, the mapped type uses the `-?` [mapping modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers) to make sure that any optional properties in `T` don't be come "optional" in the output, otherwise you'll allow `undefined` to be a `PartOfObjectType<T>`.  For the example as shown this is unnecessary.)

Let's test it out:

```
interface CarType {
  name: string;
  price: number;
}

type CarPart = PartOfObjectType<CarType>
/*  type CarPart = {
    prop: "name";
    value: string;
} | {
    prop: "price";
    value: number;
} */
```

You can see that `CarPart` has one union member for each property of `CarType`, with the desired structure.  And that gives you the desired results for your test code:

```
const partOfFerrari: PartOfObjectType<CarType> = {
  prop: "price",
  value: 300000 
} // okay

const partOfFerrari2: PartOfObjectType<CarType> = {
  prop: "price",
  value: false // error
}

const partOfFerrari3: PartOfObjectType<CarType> = {
  prop: "name",
  value: "Banana" 
} // okay

const partOfFerrari4: PartOfObjectType<CarType> = { // error
  prop: "name",
  value: 342123 
}

const partOfFerrari5: PartOfObjectType<CarType> = {
  prop: "color", // error
  value: 342123
}

const partOfFerrari6: PartOfObjectType<CarType> = { // error
  prop: "name",      
}

const partOfFerrari7: PartOfObjectType<CarType> = { // error
  value: "Ferrari F50",
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-ru60JeNS2uy0Qc7sN1PjdqTKY5SidxFdrZ96Eg-vKgeD8FDk-DltQ0bG7dtidT3KBmaLQpFciJhezxd4A1liQolaVyxrG0ysHrWreSIAQsh0uk1m2TWacnlCtal-ae32XTdD0vWrOBhzSK94CDEMQOmBAjkKedY0XBMWSYZM2R7VdeRMDdczkAAWXceklA8y2PeUFgJFZ7kRG89jvIwiQIvMAEY8yJN8O0TdDu0dZ0B29FZfRHREoInKc4M-Y4CiQuNfy7TDOWw9c903SFMWIiU+lLOAj1QYYqOVGj1kBBwOTxN84k4czUHgFhOFgDheNoOg5BBBQWgo2AG0Y3UWPYok5JQzsXJXdM1z5PDhUhAA2LT92lPTy1PaiLzozVRCNRt5A4DJ3LYRCQEaGN5NQxTwozKK1PwgB2BLSKSwZvNS28DnudT8gxHF6LfFVcvgfK2EKk4kLCIA)

Answer (score 0):

```
export type PropertyType = 'string' | 'number';

export interface StringValidator<T extends PropertyType = 'string'> {
  type: T;
  startsWith: string;
  endsWith: string;
}
export interface NumberValidator<T extends PropertyType = 'number'> {
  type: T;
  minimum: number;
  maximum: number;
}

export type PropertyValidators = StringValidator | NumberValidator;

const goodTyping: PropertyValidators = {
  type: 'number',
  maximum: 100,
  minimum: 400,
};

const coolTyping: PropertyValidators = {
  type: 'string',
  startsWith: 'y',
  endsWith: 'z',
};

const shitTyping: PropertyValidators = {
  type: 'number',
  startsWith: 'y',
  endsWith: 'z',
};
```